# Uploading multiple files uploads only one

Tags: php, arrays, file, upload, push

This function uploads only 1 file instead of 6. The reason is that it returns  array `$fileDirectories` with dimension 1 instead of 6 and I can't understand why. `count($_FILES['file']['name'])` echoes 6.

```
function uploadFile( $link){

        $fileDirectories = array();
        echo 'count files: '.count($_FILES['file']['name']).'<br>';
        for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++){


                        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$i],
                                            "../upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"][$i]);
                        $fileDirectory = "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"][$i];
                        array_push($fileDirectories, $fileDirectory);
                        return $fileDirectories;


        }
echo 'array count:'.count($fileDirectories).'<br>';
//echoes 1 when it suppose to be 6 file directories.
//it also uploads to ftp server only 1 of them
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `return $fileDirectories;` statement outside the for loop.

Comment: thanks alot man i wonder how i didnt see it. I guess its because I was working on solving mistakes for 7 hours staight. thanks again good luck